# RSpec stubbing and checking arguments when an object's constructor instantiates another

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given the code below, how would I go about verifying in an RSpec test
that the constructor of class B calls the constructor of class A with
the right argument?

```
class A
  def initialize(*args)
  end  
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    super(1)
  end  
end
```

The test I have works as long as I don't check the arguments (leave out the ".with")

```
describe B do 
  describe '#new' do
    it { 
      allow(A).to receive(:new).with(any_args)                                                                                                                                     
      B.new
      expect(A).to have_received(:new).with(1)
    }    
  end  
end
```

Adding the check for the arguments gives me the following error:

```
B
  #new
    should have received new(1) 1 time (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) B#new should have received new(1) 1 time
     Failure/Error: expect(A).to have_received(:new).with(1)

       #<A (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
         expected: (1)
              got: (no args)
```

This seems to indicate the constructor for class A gets called without
arguments?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super` in your `initialize` method for `B`, it calls `initialize` in  `A`, not `new`.  You could test that an instance of `A` receives `initialize` with one argument:

```
expect_any_instance_of(A).to receive(:initialize).with(1)
B.new
```

But RSpec will complain at you for stubbing `initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

You're maybe better off checking for side effects (why do you want `super` to be called?) or verify that super was called:

```
  expect_any_instance_of(B).to have_received(:super).with(1)
```